# Double WHERE NOT statement sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,
                 name,
                 highest_score,
                 num_tries,
                 avg_total 
            FROM users 
       WHERE NOT played_game = '0' 
        ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

Where I select `pic_square`,`name`,`highest_score`,`num_tries` and `avg_total` FROM for all users that

**DO NOT have their played game set as ''0''.**

---

**I would like to add another condition so I select only the users that:**

- **DO NOT have their played_game set as ''0''**
- **DO NOT have their name empty**

**PS:** *The name cannot be null, it just can be empty, I cannot change the DB structure itself.*

So how do I add these dual WHERE NOT together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE NOT (played_game = '0' or name = '')
```

or

```
WHERE played_game <> '0' and name <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,name,highest_score,num_tries,avg_total FROM users 
  WHERE NOT (played_game = '0' OR name IS NULL OR name='' ) 
  ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,name,highest_score,num_tries,avg_total FROM users 
  WHERE played_game <> '0' AND name <> ''  ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

simply change condition like

```
where played_game <> '0' AND name <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,
                 name,
                 highest_score,
                 num_tries,
                 avg_total 
            FROM users 
           WHERE NOT played_game = '0' 
             AND IFNULL(name,'') <> ''
        ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

Using `IFNULL` you'll get sure that `NULL` values and empty values are treated just the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,name,highest_score,num_tries,avg_total 
          FROM users 
          WHERE played_game != '0' 
            AND name NOT NULL 
          ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```